# does docker remote api support creating a container using a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an app that creates docker containers using the docker remote api, which is done using [this](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) library.

So far it is working fine with simple configuration options for the container creation. Now I need to create the container with much more config options, so wondering if i can use a docker-compose file. This api is created based on v1.23 of docker remote api spec, does docker remote api support creating a container using a compose file?

I cannot find an option from [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.23/#2-endpoints) documentation. but wondering if i am looking in wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; Docker Compose itself is an application that uses the API.  You’d need to directly run `docker-compose up` or something similar as a shell command if you wanted to directly use it.

(You might be able to hack into its internals if you have a Python program, but not from Java.)

Comment: Yes, I realized that a bit late. Thanks for the response though.